# Entering df.groupby....max() result into a new column. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My data is related to `"Cricket"`, sports game (like Baseball). It has `20 overs for each inning max` and `each over has approx 6 balls`.

data:

```
        season  match_id    inning  sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets   over/ball   innings_score
32      2008    60          1       61              0                   5.1         0
33      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.2         0
34      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.3         0
35      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.4         0
36      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.5         0
...     ...     ...         ...     ...             ...                 ...         ...
179073  2019    11415       2       152             5                   19.2        0
179074  2019    11415       2       154             5                   19.3        0
179075  2019    11415       2       155             6                   19.4        0
179076  2019    11415       2       157             6                   19.5        0 
179077  2019    11415       2       157             7                   19.6        0
```

111972 rows × 7 columns

`innings_score` is new column created by me (given default value 0). I want to update it.
The values that I want to enter in it are the results of `df.groupby` below.

```
In[]:
df.groupby(['season', 'match_id', 'inning'])['sum_total_runs'].max()

Out[]:
season  match_id  inning
2008    60        1         222
                  2          82
        61        1         240
                  2         207
        62        1         129
                           ... 
2019    11413     2         170
        11414     1         155
                  2         162
        11415     1         152
                  2         157
Name: sum_total_runs, Length: 1276, dtype: int64
```

I want `innings_score` to be like:

```
        season  match_id    inning  sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets   over/ball   innings_score
32      2008    60          1       61              0                   5.1         222
33      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.2         222
34      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.3         222
35      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.4         222
36      2008    60          1       61              1                   5.5         222
...     ...     ...         ...     ...             ...                 ...         ...
179073  2019    11415       2       152             5                   19.2        157
179074  2019    11415       2       154             5                   19.3        157
179075  2019    11415       2       155             6                   19.4        157
179076  2019    11415       2       157             6                   19.5        157
179077  2019    11415       2       157             7                   19.6        157
```

111972 rows × 7 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `assign`. Starting from a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame({"name1":["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"], "name2":["C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"], "value":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
grouping_variables = ["name1", "name2"]
dt = dt.set_index(grouping_variables)
dt = dt.assign(new_column=dt.groupby(grouping_variables)["value"].max())
```

As you can see, you set your `grouping_variables` as indeces before running the assignment.

You can always reset the index at the end if you don't want to keep the `grouping_variables` indexed dataframe:

```
dt.reset_index()
```

Comment: None of ['season', 'match_id', 'inning'] are in the columns

Comment: thanks i ran the whole file again and it worked fine.

Comment: i already had made those three columns as index before pasting your code. So, it was saying there are no columns as such.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set those 3 columns as index and assign the groupby result as a new column and reset index after that.

While those columns are index, the grouby result and the dataframe both have similar index, so pandas will automatically match and insert the correct rows in the correct positions. Then reset index will turn them back into normal columns.

Something like this:

```py
In [46]: df
Out[46]:
   season  match_id  inning  sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets  over/ball
0    2008        60       1              61                  0        5.1
1    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.2
2    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.3
3    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.4
4    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.5
5    2019     11415       2             152                  5       19.2
6    2019     11415       2             154                  5       19.3
7    2019     11415       2             155                  6       19.4
8    2019     11415       2             157                  6       19.5
9    2019     11415       2             157                  7       19.6

In [47]: df.set_index(['season', 'match_id', 'inning']).assign(innings_score=df.groupby(['season', 'match_id', 'inning'])['sum_total_runs'].max()).reset_index()
Out[47]:
   season  match_id  inning  sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets  over/ball  innings_score
0    2008        60       1              61                  0        5.1             61
1    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.2             61
2    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.3             61
3    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.4             61
4    2008        60       1              61                  1        5.5             61
5    2019     11415       2             152                  5       19.2            157
6    2019     11415       2             154                  5       19.3            157
7    2019     11415       2             155                  6       19.4            157
8    2019     11415       2             157                  6       19.5            157
9    2019     11415       2             157                  7       19.6            157
```

Comment: None of ['season', 'match_id', 'inning'] are in the columns

Comment: Are you getting that error? From your question it looks like they are in the columns. Make sure to not do this on the result of the groupby but on the original dataframe.

Comment: yes they are in my df and i did this on orig df.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you ran and the traceback you see? I don't see how it would error if the dataframe looks like your original question, the groupby that you did in the question would have also failed if those columns didn't exist.

Comment: thanks i ran the whole file again and it worked fine.

Comment: i already had made those three columns as index before pasting your code. So, it was saying there are no columns as such.